# Finding all available versions of a NuGet package within a specific version range

Tags: nuget, versioning, dependency-management, package-management

I'm looking for a method to retrieve a list of all available versions of a NuGet package that fall within a specific version range, similar to the functionality provided by
npm view packageName@"versionRange" version

I have already tried using the nuget list command, but it does not provide the specific version range filtering that I require

I'm seeking a method to obtain a detailed list of package versions within a specified range. For instance, npm provides a list like:

```
npm view @babel/core@^7.12.3 version

>> @babel/core@7.12.3 '7.12.3'
>> @babel/core@7.12.7 '7.12.7'
>> @babel/core@7.12.8 '7.12.8' 
[...]
>> @babel/core@7.24.0 '7.24.0'
>> @babel/core@7.24.1 '7.24.1'
>> @babel/core@7.24.3 '7.24.3'
```

Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this using NuGet's tools or APIs would be greatly appreciated.